# Perl converting formatting date to y-m-d H:M

Tags: perl, datetime

I am running into issues converting the date `Apr  9 2017  3:45:00:000AM` to `2017-04-09 03:45:00`

Here's what i have tried.

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern   => '%h %d %Y %H:%M',);
$start_date = $strp->parse_datetime('Apr  9 2017  3:45:00:000AM');
```

prints `2017-04-09T03:45:00` and not `2017-04-09 03:45:00`.  Trying to get 24 hour clock so when i switch `AM` to `PM` the same time prints.

Comment: The code you provided doesn't print anything. You mention `AM`/`PM`, but your example is with `3:45 AM`, meaning that it is identical with 12-hour and 24-hour format, which makes your question a bit unclear. Could you add the code that does the print (it sounds like you just added an extra `T` in there...), and use `3:45 PM` rather than `3:45 AM` as your example please?

Comment: Also, I assume that the final `:000` before `AM` as milliseconds; is that right? If so, will they always be `000`, or can they be an arbitrary 3-digit number? (the answer will not be the same in both cases)

Comment: @Dada that is my code.  It is a copy paste and it prints I forgot to add `my $start_date;` But the code is what I am using and it prints `2017-04-09T03:45:00`.  So I am not sure why it's not printing for you.  yes the `:000` is miliseconds.  Yes I used AM but if you swap AM to PM i get the same result.  Which I could expect to get `2017-04-09T15:45:00` for PM.  What I am trying to produce is `2017-04-09 03:45:00` for am and `2017-04-09 15:45:00` for PM.

Comment: 1/ Your code does not contain a print, nor any function that prints anything. Please provide your actual code. 2/ You did not answer my question regarding milliseconds: are they always 000 or not?

Comment: `print "$start_date";` and no they are not always 000.

Comment: So ... you don't care for milliseconds, or do you want them?  And you want 24hr format, not AM/PM, right?  That's what I assumed in my answer please let me know if it's wrong

Comment: (I mean _when you print_ you don't want to see milliseconds and want 24hr format? See edit to my answer and please clarify if needed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**   *See end for an `strptime` pattern to parse the shown input string format correctly*

---

What is shown works,<sup>†</sup> and so the [DateTime::Format::Strptime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Strptime) constructor returns a `DateTime` object. But when an object is simply printed then one gets the [stringification](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#$dt-%3Estringify()) that is shown.

So you need to format it for printing as desired.  A general way is with [strftime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#$dt-%3Estrftime(-$format,-...-))

```
say $start_date->strftime("%F %T");
```

where both `%F` and `%T` are shorthands, see [strftime patterns](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#strftime-Patterns)

Or combine the basic `ymd` and `hms` methods

```
say $start_date->ymd('-') . ' ' . $start_date->hms(':');
```

See the docs and adjust if/as needed. I didn't understand some details.

---

<sup>†</sup> It works only by accident in this exact example, since the pattern given to use for parsing in `new` is wrong for the shown input format, and is also inconsistent with stated requirements

- The shown pattern doesn't have a format specifier for the seconds, nor for the milliseconds that follow it, nor for the following `AM/PM` -- all expected in the input string. So in general an input in the shown form cannot be parsed correctly with the shown pattern
- The `%H` matches `00-23` hour, so not 12-hour clock which is stated as expected and is implicit by the presence of `AM`. (It still matches a 12-hour-time number but it won't once the missing AM/PM format specifier is added.)

The pattern in the OP works and parses the given input correctly because `03:45...` *happens to be* in AM, *and* the module uses regex to match the given pattern anywhere in the given string (by default), so `%H:%M` matches `03:45` and the rest of the input string doesn't matter. If we turn on `strict` in the constructor this'll fail. See documentation.

Assuming that the shown input is the correct part we'd need

```
my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern => '%h %d %Y %I:%M:%S%3N%p'
);
```

Here `%I` is for 12-hour clock (1-12), added `%S` is for seconds and `%3N` for milliseconds (see the page in docs for patterns, linked above), and `%p` for AM/PM.

The rest then works as it stands, along with printing in a desired format given above.

Answer (score 1):

Following code demonstrates how desired output can be achieved without any modules

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $date   = 'Apr  9 2017  3:45:00:000AM';
my @fields = qw/month mday year hour min sec usec/;
my %months = ( Jan => 1,  Feb => 2,  Mar => 3,
               Apr => 4,  May => 5,  Jun => 6, 
               Jul => 7,  Aug => 8,  Sep => 9, 
               Oct => 10, Nov => 11, Dec => 12
            );
my %parts;

@parts{@fields} = split "[ :]+", $date;

$parts{hour} += 12 if $parts{usec} =~ /PM/;
$parts{month} = $months{ $parts{month} };

printf "%04d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d\n", 
       @parts{qw/year month mday hour min sec/};
```

Perl code with assistance of module

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use DateTime::Format::DateParse;
 
my($date, $dt);

$date = 'Apr  9 2017  3:45:00:000AM';
$date =~ s/:(\d{3}[AP]M)/.$1/;

$dt = DateTime::Format::DateParse->parse_datetime( $date );

$date = $dt;
$date =~ s/T/ /;

say $date;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your code. First, the pattern you use to parse your date is not correct: `%H` is used for a 24-hour format hour. Instead, you should use a combination of `%i` (12-hour) and `%p` (`AM`/`PM`). Second, to print a `DateTime` object, you should first format it first (using `->strftime` or `->ymd()` for instance).

The milliseconds in the date are, however, a bit of an issue because `strptime` does not have a option to match milliseconds. I suggest to first remove them from your date, and only then parse the date with `strptime`:

```
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $date = 'Apr  9 2017  3:45:00:505PM';

# Removing milliseconds from date
$date =~ s/:(\d{3})(?=AM|PM)//; 
my $milliseconds = $1;

my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => '%h %d %Y %I:%M:%S%p',);
my $start_date = $strp->parse_datetime($date);

# Taking into account the milliseconds that were removed earlier
$start_date->add(seconds => 1) if $milliseconds > 500;


say $start_date->strftime("%F %T");
```